# Iteratively collect first two elements of each vector of a matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
matrix = [['F', 'B', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'F'],
          ['D', 'E', 'B', 'E', 'B', 'E'],
          ['F', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'F', 'B'],
          ['B', 'E', 'F', 'B', 'D', 'D']]
```

I want to remove and collect the first two elements of each sub-list, and add them to a new list.

so far i have got:

```
while messagecypher:
    for vector in messagecypher:
        final.extend(vector[:2])
```

the problem is; the `slice` doesn't seem to remove the elements, and I end up with a huge list of repeated chars. I could use `.pop(0)` twice, but that isn't very clean.

NOTE: the reason i remove the elements is becuase i need to keep going over each vector until the matrix is empty

Comment: I don't think you want `vector[2:]` there. Even if slicing removed elements from the list, that would be a slice *starting* at index 2 and including everything after that index, rather than a slice containing just the first two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you *can* use a list comprehension to get the thing done, but its perhaps counter-intuitive:

```
>>> matrix = [['F', 'B', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'F'],
          ['D', 'E', 'B', 'E', 'B', 'E'],
          ['F', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'F', 'B'],
          ['B', 'E', 'F', 'B', 'D', 'D']]
>>> while [] not in matrix: print([i for var in matrix for i in [var.pop(0), var.pop(0)]])
['F', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'A', 'B', 'E']
['F', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'B', 'F', 'B']
['C', 'F', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'B', 'D', 'D']
```

EDIT:

Using `range` makes the syntax look cleaner:

```
>>> matrix = [['C', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'B'], ['D', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'C', 'B'], ['B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'F']] 
>>> while [] not in matrix: print([var.pop(0) for var in matrix for i in range(2)])
['C', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'A']
['B', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'F', 'C', 'B']
['F', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'F']
```

Comment: I need to go back over the matrix and collect the next two elements until the matrix is empty

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your `slice` and do:

```
final = []
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    matrix[i], final = matrix[i][:2], final + matrix[i][2:]
```

Note that this simultaneously assigns the sliced list back to `matrix` and adds the sliced-off part to `final`.

Comment: Probably the best solution right now. I'll have a look at itertools again.

Comment: i have changed my question: vector[:2] to vector[2:] but i think this may work ill test it

Comment: when i use this method the first 4 couples are correct but the others appear to be random elements:

Answer (score 0):

Deleting elements is not an efficient way to go about your task. It requires Python to perform a lot of unnecessary work shifting things around to fill the holes left by the deleted elements. Instead, just shift your slice over by two places each time through the loop:

```
final = []
for i in xrange(0, len(messagecypher[0]), 2):
    for vector in messagecypher:
        final.extend(vector[i:i+2])
```

Comment: I wrote up a version using list comprehensions, but when I got to the point of having 3 `for` clauses in one comprehension, I decided to just do it this way.